# No conecta base de datos oracle con PHP a través de PDO

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-11g

Quiero conectar la base de datos de oracle Schema hr por defecto que viene en la bd de oracle a traves de PDO con php pero me lanza este error

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]:
>   pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect
>   identifier specified (ext\pdo_oci\oci_driver.c:640) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ORACLE\52conexion3.php:9 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ORACLE\52conexion3.php(9):
>   PDO->__construct('oci:host=localh...', 'hr', 'hr') #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ORACLE\52conexion3.php on line 9

El nombre de la bd en oracle es 
**Schema - HR**
el usuario es **hr** y la contraseña es **hr** asi que deberia funcionar pero no lo hace...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

    $base = new PDO('oci:host=localhost/XE; dbname= Schema - HR', 'hr','hr');

?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Intentos realizados y sigue sin funcionar**

```
$base = new PDO('oci:host=localhost;dbname=Schema - HR', 'hr','hr');

$base = new PDO("oci:host=localhost;dbname=Schema - HR", "hr","hr");

$base = new PDO("oci:host=localhost/XE;dbname=Schema - HR", "hr","hr");

$base = new PDO("oci:host=XE;dbname=Schema - HR", "hr","hr");

$base = new PDO('oci:host=localhost;dbname="Schema - HR"', 'hr','hr');
```

Comment: En la cadena de conexión hay una serie de espacios en blanco que quizás podrían estar creando problemas. Tal y como está ahora parecería que el nombre de la base de datos es ` Schema - HR` (con un espacio al principio). Prueba eliminando ese espacio a ver qué pasa. Además, si el nombre de la base de datos contiene espacios en blanco, quizás deberías delimitarlo con comillas dobles.

Comment: le quite el espacio despues del signo = Schema... pero aun asi no funciona :l

Comment: Prueba a poner el nombre de la base de datos entre comillas dobles. Y actualiza la pregunta con las diferentes cadenas de conexión que vayas intentando para verlas

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ya probe con dobles y tampoco, tambien edite el post al final estan mis intentos .

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro en el sql developer en la conexion donde esta la bd de shema le di click derecho para ver que los datos que ingrese sean correctos y al parecer si porque dice
Nombre de conexion: Schema - HR
usuario: hr
contraseña: hr

alias de la red: XE

Comment: Con las comillas dobles no me refería a eso, sino a esto: `$base = new PDO('oci:host=localhost;dbname="Schema - HR"', 'hr','hr');`

Comment: tampoco funcionó, lo agregaré a la lista dl post

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro probe con otra bd que tengo y tampoco me funciona :s no se si se refiere a otro usuario y contraseña o qué. ...

Comment: Creo que me he centrado demasiado en esos espacios en blanco y no en el mensaje. Parece que hay un problema con el identificador del conector especificado. ¿Qué versión de PHP usas? ¿Tienes activado pdo_oci en PHP.ini? ¿Tienes el driver de OCI instalado?

Comment: no sé que version estoy usando, creo que la ultima porque me descargué el xamp , creo que si tengo activado el pdo porque en el .ini esta asi
extension=php_pdo_oci.dll y no tiene el ";" detras.. puedo conectarme a la bd perfectamente desde el otro metodo, pero cuando encontre el del PDO ahi ya no me funciona :s

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usarlo de manera separada:

```
define('DBHOST','localhost');
define('DBUSER','Schema - HR');
define('DBPASS','hr');
define('DBNAME','hr');

$base = new PDO("oci:host=" . DBHOST . ";dbname=" . DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

Comment: Lo probe como tu pero tampoco funciona, ya que es practicamente ponerlo igual que estan junto :s yo creo que hay un problema con el nombre de la bd o los usuarios y contra quizas no se refieren a los de la base de datos porque no enceuntro otra explicacion...

Answer (score 0):

En los comentarios mencionas:

> en el sql developer en la conexion donde esta la bd de shema le di click derecho para ver que los datos que ingrese sean correctos y al parecer si porque dice **Nombre de conexion**: `Schema - HR` **usuario**: `hr` **contraseña**: `hr` **alias de la red**: `XE`

De acuerdo a esta información, deberías poder conectar con la siguiente sentencia:

```
$base = new PDO('oci:dbname=XE', 'hr', 'hr');
```

Nota que no hay referencia a `Schema - HR` (que es solo un nombre lógico que se le asigna a la conexión en SQL Developer, pero no sirve para conectarse en sí), ni a `localhost`. Mas bien, solo deberías necesitar el SID `XE`, que hace referencia a una entrada en tu *tnsnames.ora* donde allí se encuentra el resto de la información necesaria para establecer la conexión (host, port, etc).

Comment: tu codigo no me funcionó pero probe asi "$base = new PDO('oci:dbname=localhost', 'hr', 'hr');" y ahoa si funciona no entiendo porque de ninguna de las otras formas no funciona si en el ejemplo que entrega PHP lo colocan de las formas que mencioné arriba :S en dbname le ponen el nombre de la base de datos y tampoco sé porque con XE no funciona siendo que en las propiedades de la bd dice que es XE xd tengo la solucion ya pero me gustaría entender el porqué

Comment: tampoco entiendo :)